# How to read items from SPview's RenderAsHTML() view?

Tags: list, development, office-365, list-view, html

I have displayed a SharePoint list view on visual webpart using
***SPview.RenderAsHtml()*** with Literal Control.

Is there any way to read these items ? I want to get selected items from this html view.

[image]

I have displayed a view on webpart with following code:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("List1");
SPView myView = list.Views["Pending"];
sb.Append("<p>" + myView.RenderAsHtml() + "</p>");
Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using javascript code.. check the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../../_layouts/15/Literal/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>


<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

<asp:Button ID="btnGetItems" runat="server" Text="Get selected items" OnClientClick="return getItems()" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getItems() {
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($("input:checked"), function () {
            favorite.push(this.title);
        });
        alert("Selected values are: " + favorite.join(", "));

        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the Solution:

Here, selected item rows contains the `<tr>`with class name `s4-itm-selected`, So I read all those rows using JavaScript.

```
var selChks = document.getElementsByClassName("s4-itm-selected");
            var chk;
            for (var i = 0; i < selChks.length; i++) {
                chk = selChks[i];
                var title = chk.cells[1].textContent.trim();
                var fname = chk.cells[2].textContent.trim();
                alert("Title="+title);
                alert("First Name="+fname);
            }
```